# Reference for existence of the trace on $R\rtimes_{\sigma_\phi}{\mathbb R} $ for $\phi$ being f.s.n. weight.

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras

I am looking for a good reference for existence of the trace on $R\rtimes_{\sigma_\phi}{\mathbb R} $ for $\phi$ being f.s.n. weight. 
For the $\phi$ being f. strictly  s.n. weight it is probably van Daele book
For the integrable $\phi$ - Connes Takesaki flow of weights
The Haagerups paper on Operator valued weights II implies lack of operator valued weight for the case when R is type III.

Comment: Please clarify what R is supposed to be in your question - given that R sometimes denotes the hyperfinite II_1 factor.

Comment: $R$ is von Neumann algebra

Comment: $\sigma_\phi$ is modular automorphisms group associated with weight $\phi$